# Configuring build profiles for Maven to change values in spring-boot properties file

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am following this tutorial so that Maven will replace values in my application.properties file depending on the build profile:

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-profile-specific-configuration-files-with-maven/

1. It states to put some config files under the "profiles" directory.  Where is this directory?  I created a folder named "profiles" in the root of the project directory.
2. How do I activate a profile?  I Googled around and I added -P to the commands, for example "mvn test" would be "mvn test -P staging"

Needless to say, it is not working.  Even when the default profile "dev" is supposed to be activated without any action necessary, my application.properties file is not affected.

Comment: Saying it clearly the tutorial is simply wrong. A spring-boot profile is something different than a maven profile. Having different profiles in spring-boot can be achieved by using `application-dev.properties` whereas the `application.properties` is the default. You can have as many as you wish. Those spring boot profiles can be activated via `--spring.profiles.active=dev` for example. No directories needed etc.

Comment: Please read the documentation of Spring boot about profiles for example https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-profiles and take look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

For spring boot aplication paramiters should be mark using `@`.

From example ebove vlaue shout be:

```
PROPERTY=@my.varible@
```

Answer (score -1):

The tutorial I linked above worked.  The only difference is that when using for Spring Boot with the spring-boot-starter-parent

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

The format of the placeholder string is

and not

```
${my.variable}
```